# callback in when/done never getting called

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

In situations where there are no entries in either of my collections, the render function never got called. Question: What is the bare minimum that needs to be returned for a jQuery when/done to resolve?

```
$.when(collection2.fetch(), collection2.fetch())
    .done(function(data, data2){
        ...
        _this.render();
    });
```

Note, I tagged this question with Backbone.js to indicate that the fetch request is a Backbone.Collection.fetch().

Comment: You need to return a resolved promise if the collection is empty (and you want it to still hit done with no data)

Comment: You need to show the code in `fetch` for an answer that makes specific sense for you :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussi it's a Backbone.Collection.fetch() that's why I tagged Backbone.js. Sorry, I didn't make that clear. Will update OP.

Comment: Ah... Okay, not sure when you would hook it then. Perhaps a wrapper around fetch? How/when do you know the collection is empty?

Comment: No return value from `.fetch()` ? `undefined` not returned ? `$.when()` should return jQuery promise object if no argument passed ; e.g;, `$.when().done(fn)` . See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when _"If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when() and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately. The doneCallbacks are passed the original argument."_. Try attaching `.fail(function(err) {console.log(err)})` , calling `_this.render()` at `.fail()` or `.always()`

Comment: Is `_this` defined within `.done()` ?

Comment: @Leahcim Not tried `backbone.js` , though `$.when()` call `.done()` even if `undefined` passed as argument; or no argument at all passed. Can create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code for `fetch`, I can only suggest the minimum.

If your collection is empty, return `$.Deferred().resolve().promise()` from `fetch()` and it run `done` immediately (immediately upon *both* promises being resolved of course)

Comment: Did you see my comment? It's a Backbone.Collection.fetch()?  Either way, how do I rewrite the OP to integrate your code, is there a different `branch` (for lack of a better word) if `.done` never executes?

Comment: I did. I have seen some extensions of fetch on SO that might allow the hook, but if both `done` and `fail` do not fire (please check `fail` too), then there is something wrong with the `fetch` promise. `always()` will fire after `done` or `fail` conditions if that helps.